# Make a faux call on old 1950s touch tone phone

Tags: telephone, keypad

I have a 1950s ice cream shop and just bought a vintage touch tone phone. It works if I connect it to a phone line but I won't be doing this. What I really want to do is pre-record messages that will play if someone dials a certain set of numbers. They do this at Universal in Harry Potter World. If you press 5 numbers it "connects you to the Ministry of Magic".

I really don't know where to start so hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: ["Touch-tone" didn't exist in the 1950s.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push-button_telephone)  It came out in 1963.

Comment: My parents bought a ‘63 style home and I found at 50’s vintage dialup phone, painted it gold-fleck green like AMC cars of the day and converted it into a conference speaker phone with my old reel-reel tape recorder hot-wired to it.

Comment: They have chips that you can record messages on and push buttons to select one of many recordings.  Look online for such kits.

Comment: There's a whole lot of ways to do this.  All of them would take much more explanation than is practical in an answer.

Comment: You could tear the phone apart, and install an microcontroller based keypad reader and mp3 player in it.

Comment: You could power it externally, and build a microprocessor based gadget to decode the touch tones and playback audio over the telephone lines.

Comment: You could connect the phone to a modern VOIP adapter, then point that VOIP adapter to a Raspberry Pi running Asterisk with a dial up menu implemented.

Comment: You could externally power the phone then connect it to a PC with a DTMF decoder and a playback program.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is basically a request for complete instructions for a project.

Comment: Could you update your question to describe your own type and level of knowledge and experience?

Comment: You can buy an Analog Telephone Adapter, which converts a phone call into a VOIP call, and then run a "fake" VOIP phone network on a computer. I've done that.

Comment: Joey Martin - Hi, "*I really don't know where to start so hoping someone can point me in the right direction.*" Unfortunately there is no "right direction" for this broad question; there are many possible directions, each with their pros and cons. This is one reason why broad questions aren't a good "fit" here, as there is no right (or better) answer for future readers to know is better. Hopefully the replies you've received both in comments (\*cough\*) and as answers, will give you some ideas.

Comment: Joey. (A) I don't see you interacting with anyone on this question. That suggests you may not be sufficiently serious about getting an answer. (B) But in general, you need to hire someone to do this for you. It's a perfect task for someone local who has some good experience and wants to take on a project like this. You can explain what you are trying to achieve, they can hold and examine your device and think about it, and you can get something done that works. Everything in business has to be mutual, so be fair in balancing what you expect to get and pay. I recommend paying as T&M here.

Comment: It can easily be done with off the shelf VoIP hardware/software. Eg Asterisk

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing this on an Arduino since there are plenty of guides out there for interfacing a keypad to them.  They also have I2C capability so you could hook up an audio trigger module like this: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/16892 and be off and running with a minimum of fuss.

Answer (score 1):

The phone needs to see the off-hook current loop to make tones. From there you can use a PC sound card to sample the tones, decode them, and play the selected clip.

Here’s a line of products related to this: https://www.jkaudio.com/products.htm

Related: [Connecting landline to soundcard](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4989/connecting-landline-to-soundcard)